# TCP Minecraft Server in Ruby

Tags: ruby, sockets, tcp, minecraft

I'm attempting to create a script in ruby that connects to a Minecraft server via TCP and fetches the current number of players much like the PHP script at http://www.webmaster-source.com/2012/07/05/checking-the-status-of-a-minecraft-server-with-php/

When running the code below I get `�Took too long to log in`

```
require 'socket'

server = TCPSocket.new '192.241.174.210', 25565
while line = server.gets
  puts line
end

server.close
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're not sending this:

```
 fwrite($sock, "\xfe");
```

from the script you linked.  You have to send that before you call read, like they do.

Basically the server is waiting for you to send data and when you don't after a timeout, you are disconnected.

Comment: Who knows.  I mean, the \x means to interpret the next bit as hexadecimal.  But as to why that's important?  I have no clue.  Go read about the minecraft protocol.  I'm guessing a quick google for exactly that will be informative.